# EditText doesn't appear in emulator

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a simple app for Android - RecyclerView, two Buttons and an EditText. Everything is OK except the EditText - it doesn't appear in the emulator, but it figures in the Design View. I tried different configurations - no luck.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance,
Ad.

The code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvA"
    android:layout_width="411dp"
    android:layout_height="652dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:onClick="fur"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:onClick="ed"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rvA" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you remove ` app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rvA"` from the `EditText` and check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set height of recycler view 0dp and bottom to top of buttons or editext like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Button3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rvA" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I try this on emulator and edittext is displaying fine.

Comment: Glad that I helped you @Ady